# Is it possible to have another CRS in the status bar than used for the map?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am new to QGIS.

When I use OSM or Google Maps as a basemap via OpenLayers Plugin, the map should be projected as EPSG:900913. However, the coordinates shown in the status bar are useless for me, what I need to see is lat/lon or UTM.

Is it possible to have another CRS in the status bar than used for the map?

I did find the Coordinate Capture Plugin, which can be used to follow the mouse cursor in another CRS, but this is not handy for me and conflicts with the use of other tools.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a [Python startup script](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578692-qgis-startup-script-change-display-of-coordinates/) which adds this feature.

Comment: Well that is pretty cool use of the startup script. Would you be offended if I lovingly stole that idea and made it a core feature?

Comment: @NathanW any progress on your effort?

Comment: None sorry. Maybe for the next release after 2.16

Answer (score 1):

No that's not possible.

If you describe your workflow, we might be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: Sorry, no specific workflow for now. I am learning how to use the program and how to configure the interface.