# How to quickly change EPSG in QGIS (Openlayers; 4326 vs. 3857)

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, epsg, qgis-openlayers-plugin, mercator

I'm using Qgis 2.12.2-Lyon on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

With the OpenLayers plugin I added some OpenLayers to my Canvas.
I usually use the WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) projection for my project, but I have to switch on the OpenStreetMap or BingAerial layers sometimes.

When I forget to change the projection to WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator (3857) a priori then a python error occurs:

```
(Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/home/.../.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/openlayers_layer.py", line 120, in request
            self.setup_map()
          File "/home/.../.qgis2/python/plugins/openlayers_plugin/openlayers_layer.py", line 185, in setup_map
            olSize = QSize(int(olWidth), int(olHeight))
        OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer).
```

And the project is loading in perpetuity (sometimes crashes running on Windows).

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Is it possible to create a short-key to change from any EPSG to WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator (3857)?

Is it possible to have a drop down menu at the bottom right of the Canvas where you can change the EPSG a bit faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar question was asked before: [Is it possible to have another CRS in the status bar than used for the map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60392/is-it-possible-to-have-another-crs-in-the-status-bar-than-used-for-the-map) and the asker finally wrote this piece of code:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578692/

But I got stuck with it sometimes on startup.

You might be better of with the new QuickMapServices plugin, which can deal with different projections far better than the openlayers plugin.